# WPF DataGrid RowDataBound?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Ok this is driving me mad, I feel like a total Newbie.

I'm using WPF's DataGrid control from WPF Toolkit with .NET 3.5.
[Link on Codeplex here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)

I want an equivalent to the classic GridView's RowDataBound event, and I can't find any. I tried working with `LoadingRow`, but it fires every time I scroll.

I'm trying to change the background color of certain cells in my grid based on a database values. 
I'm new to WPF. Should I be using the XAML binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up disabling row virtualization on the DataGrid using `EnableRowVirtualization="False"`. That way, the LoadingRow event would fire only once for all items.

Answer (score 1):

The apt way of doing that in WPF is through [Datatrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="WA">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

that comprehends to

```
UPDATE DataGrid
SET Foreground = 'Red'
WHERE State = 'WA';
```